# How to add custom key maps in CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror, keymaps

I want add 'Alt-Space' key map to codemirror and then perform a particular function when the keys are pressed. I am not able to add this keymap using      .

```
cm.addKeyMap
```

Where should I be writing this function so that the key map can be bound to a particular function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is the exact code you are using?

For your information, you can always add any keyMap to the editor instance by the following lines of code :

```
var map = {"Alt-Space": function(cm){...}}
editor.addKeyMap(map);
```

where, editor is the CodeMirror instance.